# Magento 1.9.3.1: Prevented a potential Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability when adding a category

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, upgrade, security, magento1.9.3.1

As you may know 1.9.3.1 has been been released.

In the release notes, I found that on top of bug fixes, there also was two security features:

> - Prevented a potential Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) vulnerability by changing the form key when a customer signs out of
>     the storefront.
> - Prevented a potential Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability when adding a category.

I found the code change related to the first point in `Mage/Customer/Model/Session` however, **I can't get my hands on the changes made to apply the second security feature.** Anyone could enlighten me here ?

Comment: hmm, not sure.  I did a `diff` between the last two versions but couldn't see anything either.  Just posting it here in case it helps.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bde76d7150804c899962976b6754026b

Comment: @Holy agreed. I think (hope) it's a wrong copy/paste from the Magento team and there was only one security feature in this release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the confirmation from a Magento team member that the second security fix:

> Prevented a potential Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability when
>   adding a category.

Is **only affecting EE.**

Answer (score 1):

Prevented a potential Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability when adding a category.

Maybe something related to the alert when the category is added

This is my guess:
[image: My best guess]

Comment: I don't see such changes in the diff between 1.9.3.0 and 1.9.3.1: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bde76d7150804c899962976b6754026b

Comment: I skipped 1.9.3.0, those are the diffs between 1.9.2.4 with SUPEE-8788 and 1.9.3.1. So I guess you are right, maybe it was a bad copy/paste from Magento.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking too I hope it's a bad copy/paste rather than a security breach disclosure without the bug fix